# Preview: Remove all annotations

Tags: pdf, preview

Is it possible, using Preview (or maybe some other tool if not doable with Preview, but Preview preferably) to remove *all* annotations from a PDF file, without manually deleting every annotation?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In the "Tools menu", choose "show inspector". In the inspector, select "Annotations inspector".

Press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all annotations, then click <kbd>backspace</kbd> to delete them.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It even recognises and removes annotation made by other programs!
 (Tested with annotations made by PDF Expert on the iPad.)

Answer (score 0):

[PDF Expert](https://pdfexpert.com/) can do this!

In menu bar, <kbd>Edit</kbd> then <kbd>Remove All Annotations</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Question asks explicitly about Preview, and there is an answer which shows that it is straight forward with preview. Why would I want another tool than the built in one for just this?